# Bash script, run echo command with find, set a variable and use that variable

Tags: bash, find, command

I want to run two commands but the second command depends on the first.

Is there a way to do something like this.

```
 find . -name '*.txt' -exec  'y=$(echo 1); echo $y' {} \;
```

...

And actually, I want to do this.
Run the find command, change to that directory that the file is in and then run the command on the file in the current directory.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec 'cd basedir && /mycmd/' {} \;
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find's `-exec` option expects an executable with arguments, not a command, but you can use `bash -c cmd` to run an arbitrary shell command like this:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname {}) && pwd && /mycmd $(basename {})' \;
```

I have added `pwd` to confirm that `mycmd` executes in the right directory. You can remove it. `dirname` gives you the directory of each file and `basename` gives you the filename. If you omit `basename` your command will receive (as `{}`) pathname to each file relative to the directory where you run `find` which is different from `mycmd`'s current directory due to `cd`, so `mycmd` will likely fail to find the file. If you want your command to receive absolute pathname, you can try this:

```
find $PWD -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'cd $(dirname {}) && pwd && /mycmd {}' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

find actually has a primary that switches to each file's directory and executes a command from there:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -execdir /mycmd {} \;
```